# Web client in vSphere hypervisor (free ESXi) 5.0.0 missing

Tags: vmware-esxi, hypervisor

Just installed the hypervisor and it is up and running fine (in Test mode).
Using the corresponding version of vSphere Client works fine too.
Now sites like [this](http://www.ntpro.nl/blog/archives/1788-vSphere-5-Video-The-vSphere-Web-Client.html) show a Web Client that I just cannot see.
When I visit https://my-esxi5/, the vSphere Welcome Screen does not show the Web Client link at the right side. Also, https://my-esxi5:9443/ seems to not be an open port.

Is it available at all in the free version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. [Link to the feature faq.](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/faq.html)

Comment: I can't see the explicit information that confirms this - nevertheless it seems to be correct. What a shame - this was the only feature I switched to 5 for... Thanks for answering!

Comment: They wouldn't make much money if they gave away the useful stuff. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Proxmox VE](http://pve.proxmox.com/). It is much more bare bones than a proper vSphere installation and in the free (as in freedom - not as in beer like ESXi) version it does not offer the fuzzy feeling of help from support if ever needed. (Not that I am a believer in a fully supported stack at all...)

But it does run fully virtualized Windows VMs (KVM) alongside Container virtualized Linuxes (OpenVZ), is completely adminstrable from a web browser, capable of forming clusters, doing live migrations and snapshot backups.

The right tool for the (my simple) job.

Comment: The question was explicit about a feature of ESXi. Obviously, there are other solutions, but that doesn't matter in this context.